# How to compile SIPP with pcap on cygwin64?

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to compile SIPP on cygwin64 on windows 7 64 bit with enabling pcap according to the official sipp documentation here:

> http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html#Installing+SIPp

There is a warning in the above link about my error however I couldn't understand how to avoid it. Here is the warning:

> Warning
>
> SIPp compiles under CYGWIN on Windows, provided that you installed IPv6 >extension for CYGWIN (http://win6.jp/Cygwin/), as well as libncurses and  >(optionally OpenSSL and WinPcap). SCTP is not currently supported.

When I try to run the ./configure on my cygwin64 setup here is what I get:

```
$ ./configure --with-pcap
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for initscr in -lcurses... no
configure: error: ncurses library missing
```

Several related outputs:

```
cygcheck -c ncurses
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version            Status
ncurses              6.0-4.20160305     OK

cygcheck -c libncurses-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version            Status
libncurses-devel     6.0-4.20160305     OK
```

I think I need help to install pcap and ncurses on cygwin64 because it seems like it is unable to find correct libraries.

Comment: Maybe you need to install [ncurses for Win64 toolchain](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fmingw64-x86_64-ncurses%2Fmingw64-x86_64-ncurses-6.0-4.20160305&grep=ncurses)

Comment: check config.log for the error message of the step `checking for initscr in -lcurses... no`

Comment: @DavidPostill  _$ apt-cyg install mingw64-x86_64-ncurses_ ,
_Package mingw64-x86_64-ncurses is already installed, skipping_

Comment: @matzeri from config.log: _configure:4821: result: no
configure:4831: error: ncurses library missing_